# A connection using IP but without IP possible?

Tags: ip

By writing in my shell the instruction that displays all the connections that my computer has, I realize that some IPs are displayed like this: `0.0.0.0`, `*:*`, `[::]`, `[::1]` and even stranger, on some ports no port is specified or all simply zero... If there is no port or just no IP, why does the computer display this to me as a connection ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between 127.0.0.1 and 0.0.0.0?](https://superuser.com/questions/949428/whats-the-difference-between-127-0-0-1-and-0-0-0-0)

Comment: Not exactly, but thank you for the link, it's interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am *guessing* that the instruction is some form of `netstat` command. (Please include the actual command, however. We're not mind readers.)

1. Connections to `[::1]` are normal: it is the IPv6 address of *localhost*, equal to `127.0.0.1` in IPv4. Many programs use such loopback connections internally, for communication between their own components.
2. Both `[::]` and `0.0.0.0` are "wildcard" addresses and mean the address isn't known yet. This means the line does not actually represent an active connection.

   Netstat doesn't just show connections; it **also** shows sockets which are *listening* – that is, waiting to receive an incoming connection. Such sockets don't have a remote address because they don't know what host will connect in the future.

   Therefore the all-zeros ("any" or "null" or "unspecified") remote address is shown instead. (But many netstat-like programs just show a blank field instead.)
3. For 'listening' sockets, the local address may be all-zero for the same reason.

   A computer may have multiple IP addresses (indeed most have at least two: the loopback address and the LAN address), and a 'listening' socket may be configured to wait for connections made either to *any* of those addresses, or just a specific address. (That is, *bound* to a specific local address.)

   Most listening sockets *aren't* bound to any specific local address; they'll accept all connections. Because the local address is unspecified, it is shown as all-zeros as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, so if I understand correctly, if `netstat` displays a line with an empty IP it just means that it is a socket that is not yet connected, and therefore it has port zero. 127.0.0.0.1 is equal to `[::]`, that's fine, however what's the difference between `*:*` and `[::]:0` ? The first one doesn't even have a port number.

Comment: @Tao: Same thing. Sometimes the empty address is shown as `*`, sometimes as `[::]`/`0.0.0.0`, depending on what tool you use (Windows netstat isn't the same as Linux netstat, which isn't the same as FreeBSD netstat...) Likewise, the remote port might show up as `*` or `0` when it's unknown.

Comment: Note that while TCP requires connections to be esablished before transferring data UDP can hapilly exchange data over a socket that is only bound to a local port.

Comment: @plugwash : So these sockets, not having an address obviously established by internal programs, that "netstat" displayed me necessarily worked in UDP?

Comment: No. They could still have been TCP 'listening' sockets. "Can be" is not the same as "will necessarily be".

Comment: Okay, so the only difference is that on TCP you have to establish a connection first?