# In Google Chrome what does host-resolver-rules flag do when used with proxy-server?

Tags: google-chrome, proxy, socks-proxy, socks5

I often needs to use a Socks 5 proxy for some websites. I cannot have a system wide proxy applied (which seems to be the method preferred by Chrome), so I have a shortcut which launches a chrome instance with the `--proxy-server` parameter. It's a command suggested in some StackExchange answers and it contains this part `--host-resolver-rules="MAP * 0.0.0.0 , EXCLUDE 127.0.0.1"`. It has been working flawlessly and it still does. But after a recent update (Currently Version 118 on Linux) chrome has been giving me a warning about that `host-resolver-rules` part. The warning says `You are using an unsupported command-line flag: --host-resolver-rules=MAP * 0.0.0.0 , EXCLUDE 127.0.0.1. Stability and security will suffer.`. Despite the warning it still works. So my question is should I remove that part from the command? What does it do? Is it important?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part about
`--host-resolver-rules="MAP * 0.0.0.0 , EXCLUDE 127.0.0.1"`
means:

> Direct all IPv4 domains to be resolved by my local machine except for the IP `127.0.0.1`.

The `0.0.0.0` IP address usually stands for the default
routing address for IPv4 addresses.
The `127.0.0.1` IP address stands for the local
host computer and is handled by the loopback mechanism
differently than other IP addresses.

You may read more about it in the post
[What's the difference between 127.0.0.1 and 0.0.0.0?](https://superuser.com/questions/949428/whats-the-difference-between-127-0-0-1-and-0-0-0-0)

If you had problem with not all IP references were being
directed to your proxy, this parameter of Chrome forced
all IPv4 IPs to pass through it.

The warning message of Chrome probably means that the
`--host-resolver-rules` switch has been deprecated by the
developers. You may continue to use it as long as it works.
It may continue to work forever, or as long as the Chrome
developers won't disable it totally.

You may experiment with removing the `--host-resolver-rules`
part from the call, to see if it's really required.
Otherwise, you'll need to find a replacement when the
time comes (but not immediately).